# Java Else without IF error while calculating sales amount

Tags: java

I am getting **else without If error** while trying to compute the following:
You have just started a sales job in a department store. Your pay consists of a base salary and a commission. The base salary is 5,000. The scheme shown below is used to determine the commission rate.
Sales Amount              Commission Rate
0.01–5,000              8 percent
5,000.01–10,000         10 percent
10,000.01 and above      12 percent
Your goal is to earn 30,000 a year. Write a program that finds out the minimum number of sales you have to generate in order to make 30,000.

Although  I  am not yet  sure if   my algorithm  is  right too, since I  need   to  resolve the  error first. Thank  you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Commissionsales {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create scanner
        Scanner s = new  Scanner(System.in);
        double  saleAmount = s.nextDouble();
        double   salary = 5000;
        int   target = 30000;
        int sale = 0;
        while (salary<=target){
            if(saleAmount<5000){

                double  commissionrate = 0.08;
                double commission  = commissionrate*saleAmount;
                salary+=commission;
                sale++;
            }
            System.out.println("The  minimum  sales  needed  to  earn 30,000:"+ sale);
            break;

            else if ((5000<saleAmount) && (saleAmount<10000))
            {
                double    commissionrate = 0.10;
                double commission = commissionrate*saleAmount;
                salary+=commission;  
                sale++;
            }   
            System.out.println("The  minimum  sales  needed  to  earn 30,000:"+ sale);
            break;
            else if (saleAmount>10000){
                double commissionrate = 0.12;
                double commission =commissionrate*saleAmount;
                salary+=commission;
                sale++;
            }
            break;

        }
        System.out.println("The  minimum  sales  needed  to  earn 30,000:"+ sale);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have statements between the `if` clause and the `else` clause. Move the print statements inside one of the blocks.

Comment: Try indenting your code properly and you should be able to see that your `else`s don't correctly follow `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have `System.out.println` this way:

```
...
}
System.out.println("The  minimum  sales  needed  to  earn 30,000:"+ sale);
break;
else if ((5000<saleAmount) && (saleAmount<10000))
{
....
```

After closing `if`block, you need to write `else if` immediately, or error happens.

Comment: Thank you  for the  correction.  Besides   the  else if  error and removing  the break  statement ,  can  you  help  check, it seems the  number of  sale is  in  excess of one. Also, why  will it  only  run once  with the break statement?

Comment: Now, I see that you read `saleAmount = s.nextDouble();` only once, before `while` loop. You need to do the reading inside of the loop, if you want to see other sales. Other error is, that in case of `saleAmount == 5000`or `saleAmount == 10000` there is no `if`case to process it.